# Discovering group names within matrix for using on RunningValue function

Tags: ssrs-2008

How can I find out what are the group names that can be fed into RunningValue function within a matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the names you see under Row Groups or Column Groups in the Designer:

[image]

e.g. `Team` in the above screenshot.

You can confirm this in the **Group Properties**:

[image]

If you can't see that panel, make sure that Report -> Grouping is ticked:

[image]

Comment: yeah, I just figured that out too!